# Is there automatic ETag handling in OData with WebApi 2 and Entity Framework (code first)?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, etag

WCF Data Services with Entity Framework is automatically handling **ETag** headers (defined using  [[ETagAttribute]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.etagattribute.aspx) or automagically from [[TimestampAttribute]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.timestampattribute.aspx)).

I created WebApi2 OData controller from scaffolding. My entity have a valid timestamp (rowversion) property. However I don't see the ETag header in http response.

How can I enable valid ETag handling with **OData + Web Api 2 + EF 6**?

Thanks, Stefan

Comment: Web API does not have ETag support currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebAPI v2.2 supports OData v4 and has support for ETags.  See the "Support for ETags" section in this MSDN [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx).  You can use either the `[TimeStamp]` attribute or the `[ConcurrencyCheck]` attribute but not both.  An example property on your model would look like:

```
[Timestamp] 
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```